# how to hide VAR value in this jQuery?

Tags: javascript

as you can see below, I'm struggling to hide the answer var value using jQuery

```
answer[0] = "どうぞ ";
answer[1] = " 宜しく";
answer = "L1: " + answer[0] + "." + answer[1];

document.querySelector(".l1").innerHTML = answer;

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
   $(this).answer[0].addClass('hidewithunderscore');
    });
});
```

the page loads the inner HTML element as: L1: どうぞ . 宜しく
what I'm trying to do is after the when the button click I wanna hide ONLY answer[0] and answer[1] but keep the string between visible.

```
  <div class="l1"></div>
```

CSS

```
.lang1.hidewithunderscore {
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #222;
    padding-bottom: 0px;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).answer[0].addClass('hidewithunderscore');` wont work since there is no sub-element named answer[0] for this item.

The `answer` variable is just a string here. So in order to make them transparent, update the string and send it in value.

For example, you code should be like this:

```
answer[0] = "どうぞ ";
answer[1] = " 宜しく";
answer = "L1: " + answer[0] + "." + answer[1];
answer_blank = "L1: " + "    " + "." + "     "

document.querySelector(".l1").innerHTML = answer;

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
   document.querySelector(".l1").innerHTML = answer_blank;
    });
});
```

You can adjust the space in the answer_blank variable accordingly.

Comment: If answer variable is a string, then how answer[0]= "どうぞ " will work? What I understand from your code is answer variable must be an array and answer_blank must be a string.

Comment: I think you should use different variable name for the string answer. Look, the variable name answer has been used 2 times. When used as `answer[0]` , it is an array. But the same name has been used again in the third line. So the answer variable will be overwritten by the string `"L1: " + answer[0] + "." + answer[1];`
Finally the answer variable remains a string. 
That's why I recommend another variable named answer_blank which contains the string with blank details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your Jquery is impossible, you cannot addClass to a non html element. I'm not sure I understood well your need, but I hope that will help:

```
answer1 = "どうぞ ";
answer2 = " 宜しく";
answer = 'L1: <span class="answer1">' + answer1 + '</span>.<span 
class="answer2">' + answer2 + '</span>';

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".questionOne").html(answer);
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        $(".questionOne").find(".answer1").addClass('hidewithunderscore');
    });
});
```

$(".questionOne").find(".answer1").addClass('hidewithunderscore');
means find **.answer1** inside **questionOne** and apply the class **hidewithunderscore** to this element.

Comment: button click is not changing the class !

Comment: var answer = new Array();
answer[0] = "どうぞ ";
answer[1] = " 宜しく";

document.querySelector(".questionOne").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + answer[1];

Comment: Of course! If you don't copy the code that I put, it will not work. I edited my answer with your selector.